# all github action jobs are queued and never running

Tags: github, github-actions

Updated:

2-3 days later, my job is failed automatically with the following error message.

[image]

---

faced a challenge where all of my GitHub Action jobs remained stuck in a queued state and failed to execute.

To troubleshoot, I diligently monitored the status of GitHub Actions on [githubstatus.com](https://www.githubstatus.com/) but there were no indications of system downtime or any known issues.

During my extensive search for a solution, I came across a discussion thread addressing a similar problem [link](https://github.community/t/github-action-stuck-at-queue/16869).

However, the issue seems to be older and rather perplexing, especially considering that GitHub Actions are functioning correctly on other repositories.

Here is the YAML configuration that I used:

```
jobs:
  never-running-job:
    runs-on: node:16.13-alpine3.14
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'
      - name: preinstall
        run: yarn install
      - name: build app
        run: yarn run build
      - name: test app
        run: yarn run test
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: how many actions do you have n a single workflow?

Comment: can you post your .yaml file?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra It is still queued. I executed 5~6 actions and no concurrent job. When I run past job which was success That is working done.

Comment: @JulianBPL Ok, my post is updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated**

Following the incident with GitHub Actions on February 5, it appears that, even at present, it is not functioning properly with various images other than 'ubuntu'.

To address this issue, I made the necessary modification by updating the 'runs-on' tag to 'ubuntu:latest', committed the changes, and pushed them. Consequently, GitHub successfully detected and executed my CI/CD jobs.

Initially, I had been using the node alpine image.

---

old answers

I discovered incidents listed on the GitHub page that align with the error I encountered. It is possible that these incidents are influencing the prolonged queued status.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think I had a typo... But basically I changed this line

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest      -
```

to

```
runs-on: ${{ fromJSON('["ubuntu-latest", "self-hosted"]')[github.repository == 'github/docs-internal'] }}
```

And now it works.

Comment: Can you explain why this fixed it for you?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest... Did it work or not work for you?

Comment: It worked for me. Mine was `ubuntu-18.04`, and it stayed in queued status forever. After I updated it as @ChrisStryczynski suggested, it ran instantly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my `ci.yml` and `cd.yml` files, both had got this line:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: debian-11
```

By changing `debian-11` to `ubuntu-latest` everything got fixed and Github kicked off to run the commands.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to GitHub's support of images.
Read more at https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images.

I my case, I have to change from:

```
jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
```

to

```
jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

And keeping it pointing to `-latest` will help avoid such issue again in future.